# View-Based NSTableView in Swift - How to

Tags: tableview, swift, cell

I have a **NSTableView** whose cells are **view-based**.

*DataSource & Delegate are connected*, but I'm **not able to display the cell's textField string value**.

This is the code in **Objective-C, working**:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {

return 10;

}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

        NSTableCellView *cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"List" owner:self];
        [cella.textField setStringValue:"Hey, this is a cell"];

        return cell;
}
```

And here is my code in **Swift, not working** :

```
func numberOfRowsInTableView(aTableView: NSTableView!) -> Int
{
    return 10 //Casual number
}
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSTableCellView! {
    var cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("List", owner: self) as NSTableCellView!
    // setup cell without force unwrapping it
    cell.textField.stringValue = "Hey, this is a cell"
    println("Method called") //Never printed
    return cell
}
```

This is the result: (table on right side of image)

Note that the comment `//setup cell without force unwrapping it` makes no sense, I forgot to delete it.

[image: Code + Result]
[image: TableVie settings]
[image: Delegate and DataSource connected]

### What I am missing ?

***Edit***: I tried even the following with no success:

```
func numberOfRowsInTableView(aTableView: NSTableView!) -> Int
{
    return 10
}
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> AnyObject
{
    var cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("List", owner: self) as NSTableCellView
    cell.textField.stringValue = "Hey this is a cell"
    return cell;
}
```

---

Thank you all.
Alberto

Comment: in Objective-C code you have `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`, while in Swift you have `tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath)`. Surely there's `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` Swift equivalent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After hours of search, I discovered this method that works !

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn: NSTableColumn, row: Int) -> NSView
{
    var cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("List", owner: self) as NSTableCellView
    cell.textField.stringValue = "Hey, this is a cell"
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I see that you found your answer your self but from what I can see your clue was in the Return Value of Objective -C  delegate.

```
- (NSView *)tableView:...
```

The return value is a NSView.

But you should look at the [Swift/Objective -c documentaion](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForTableColumn%3arow%3a).

From the Docs:

> Providing Views for Rows and Columns
>       tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:
>
> ```
> Asks the delegate for a view to display the specified row and column.
>
> Declaration
> SWIFT
> @optional func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView!,
>       viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!,
>                      row row: Int) -> NSView!
> OBJECTIVE-C
> - (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
>    viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
>                   row:(NSInteger)row
> ```

Note the -> NSView! in the swift code also.

The new docs allow you to see the code for Swift and Objective -c side by side or one or the other. You can use a selection tab at the top of the documentation  to choose.

It also looks like your code should include the "!" for optionals

Answer (score 2):

If you change the content mode of the table view from view based to cell based the method is called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This beat me up for an hour.  Works with Swift 2.2, probably won't work for earlier or later versions:

```
 let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(myid!, owner: nil)  // You can't cast this with as! like they want you to

    if let mycell = cell as? NSTableCellView {
        mycell.textField?.stringValue = text
        return mycell
    }
```