# Load data to NSTableView in swift

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, nstableview, appdelegate

I am new to IOS/IOX development. I tried many sites to load data to my table on OSX swift using NSTableView. But all was failure.
The procedure i did was refering [View-Based NSTableView in Swift - How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346363/view-based-nstableview-in-swift-how-to)

1. Drag and droped a NSTableView, which was perfectly seen when I run the code.
2. Selected the first column and gave Identifier as "List" after setting number of columns to 1
3. In the appdelegate.swift I pasted as

   ```
   class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate,NSTableViewDataSource,NSTableViewDelegate {

       func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {

       }

       func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {

       }

       func numberOfRowsInTableView(aTableView: NSTableView!) -> Int {

           println("reached 1")
           return 10
       }

       func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn: NSTableColumn, row: Int) -> NSView {

           println("reached 2")

           var cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("List", owner: self) as NSTableCellView

           cell.textField.stringValue = "Hey, this is a cell"

           return cell

       }
   }
   ```
4. Then i tried to Set the delegate and datasource as the Appdelegate for the table view by selecting table and pointing to "App Delegate" in "Application Scene". But it was not linking
5. When i run the program , table with no cells was loaded

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are so many (simple) examples out there. I know it's hard with all those connections to be done but if you take a running example it should bring you further. Just found this on first click: http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nstableview-sample-code/

Comment: @ThomasKilian in that example i stucked at "Set the AppDelegate as the delegate and datasource for the table view" and not able to run until i delete  "@IBOutlet var window: NSWindow" &  "@IBOutlet var myTableView: NSTableView".

Comment: You need to connect them in the interface builder. Ctrl-click-drag from from the view to the AppDelegate object (from the left side browser - it's safer). This will show the possible connections.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but Ctrl-click-drag from "Table view" in View controller Scene to "App Delegate" in "Application Scene" is not connecting to me , but only "Window Controller" in "Window Controller Scene Works" for me. Is there any other procedure.

Comment: You need to tell the NSTableView where it gets the data from and who will handle events. You can do that also by setting `view.datasource = self` and `view.delegate = self` assuming that this `self` implements the NSTableViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: Another point: when starting with tableview you should use cell based instead of view based. It's easier to handle since you can return simple strings instead of creating views.

Comment: If that doesn't work, on your window (storyboard or nib file) try adding an NSObject on your window, and put the delegate as the class. It should then accept things from that interface. Maybe that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
{
    if tableView.identifier=="tableViewIdentifier" {

           let cellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("List", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = "Hey, this is a cell"
            return cellView
        }
     return nil
    }
```

set identifier to tableview of dropped table also set identifier to table column, set the delegate and datasource to the view controller in which the table is contained.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be selecting your table view in the XIB file and then in the Utilities panel on the right chose the third icon from the right (the arrow pointing right). Also make sure you show the document outline by clicking the icon in the lower left of the Interface Builder window. From the Utilities panel you can just drag from the delegate and datasource circle to your AppDelegate in the document outline.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when using storyboards, you should make your view controller a data source and delegate for your table view, because they're contained in one scene. The class itself is called `ViewController` in Xcode project templates.

So, just move the code from application delegate to view controller and connect all the things in storyboard.