# NSTableView displays empty view or placeholder "Table View Cell"

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

I'm trying to diplay list of static cell views in a NSTableView.

What I've done:

1. Added identifier to NSTableColumn (`Note`)
2. Added NSTableCellView from Object Library with identifier `idNode`
3. Left pre-created Text Cell inside NSTableColumn (`Note`) as I can't delete it

[image]

Table view content mode — View Based.

Here's my code:

```swift
extension SidebarController: NSTableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        let cellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "idNote")
        
        guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else {
            NSLog("Cant create cell view for row \(row)!")
            return nil
        }

        cellView.textField!.stringValue = "Hello, world!"

        return cellView
    }
}
```

`tableView` is:

1. called
2. no errors or short exits happens
3. a valid `cellView` is returned (at least it seems so)

But I'm getting:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

FYI, if I delete identifier for NSTableCellView, I'm just getting Table Cell View placeholder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View-Based NSTableView in Swift - How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346363/view-based-nstableview-in-swift-how-to)

Comment: @Willeke not directly, but it helped me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using wrong overloaded function. The proper was:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let cellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Note")
        
        guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else {
            NSLog("Cant create cell view for row \(row)!")
            return nil
        }
        
        cellView.textField!.stringValue = "Hello, world!"
        
        return cellView
    }
```

So, note the difference:

```
_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn
```

**The reason Xcode didn't allow me to use it — there was no `NSTableViewDelegate` in extension definition.**

This function confirms to NSTableViewDelegate. Only NSTableViewDataSource declaration is insufficient.

So, to catch up:

1. no NSTableViewDelegate
2. no way to use proper function
3. incorrect one was called anyway, so I didn't noticed the issue